# Changing Browser URL from backing bean

Tags: jsf

I would like to be able to change the text in the url bar to reflect the current state of my app (like GMail does).

Mainly i'm referring to changing the url parameters to reflect the values in my form. (Once a user enters a parameter I would like to change the url parameter that corresponds)

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: In other words, you want to use HTTP GET instead of HTTP POST? Are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? If 1.x, that's clumsy. If 2.x, that's nicely doable.

Comment: GRrrrr!! 1.2... What's the clumsy solution?
Should I be expecting trouble updating from 1.2 to 2.0. We're flexible to a degree.

Comment: Are you dependent on some component library for HTML form UI look'n'feel? As per your question history you seem to be using RichFaces.

Comment: Yes. Indeed, I have richfaces doing all the ajaxy stuff.

Comment: Hint: use `@nickname` to auto-notify others about comments on posts which are not their own. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work. Otherwise you're dependent on their eagerness to take a look back in posts where they left the comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the point, you want fire a HTTP GET request instead of a HTTP POST request. Changing the view side is trivial, use

```
<form action="targetpage.jsf">
```

instead of

```
<h:form>
```

In the managed bean which is associated with `targetpage.jsf` you however need to do a bit more changes. JSF 1.2 doesn't offer facilities to set GET request parameters for you by the view declaration, nor does it convert/validate the parameters (JSF 2.0 has `<f:viewParam>` for this).

You need to gather/convert/validate all request parameters yourself in the constructor and/or `@PostConstruct` of the backing bean and invoke the action over there as well. There are basically two ways to gather the parameters:

- Define the parameter as `<managed-property>` of the `<managed-bean>` in `faces.config.xml` so that JSF will set it for you.

  E.g.

  ```
  <h:inputText id="input" />
  ```

  *(which will generate `<input type="text" id="input" name="input" />` in HTML, it's the `name` attribute which is been used as request parameter name; rightclick page in browser and view source if you're unsure)*

  with

  ```
  <managed-property>
      <property-name>input</property-name>
      <value>#{param.input}</value>
  </managed-property>
  ```

  and

  ```
  private String input; // +setter
  ```

  EL supports automatic conversion to primitive types and their wrappers as well, so you could for numbers also use `private Long input;` instead. The caveat is however that this would throw an ugly and unhandleable exception when the value is not parseable as a number.
- Or, gather them yourself by [`ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterMap%28%29).

  ```
  public class Bean {
      private String input;

      public Bean() {
          Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
          input = params.get("input");
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

  This allows for more fine-grained conversion/validation/errorhandling.

Comment: Did you mean `<h:form action="targetpage.jsf">`? (On line 3)

Comment: No, just plain `<form>`. The `<h:form>` generates `method="post"`, you don't want that.

Comment: I get a very long line of parameters when using this method and then a blank screen. `http://localhost/d/faces/pinCodePage.jsp?j_id_jsp_1215600124_2:PinCodeInputField=dsfsd&j_id_jsp_1215600124_2:j_id_jsp_1215600124_11=Submit&j_id_jsp_1215600124_2_SUBMIT=1&javax.faces.ViewState=MC2Qwf%2BZS%2ByJjGo.....`
Any Idea why?

Comment: I have no idea what RichFaces is doing, but it look much like that you still have a parent `<h:form>` or `UINamingContainer` component somewhere in view. Did you test it with a minimum template file? The `ViewState` shouldn't be there and the command button/link should also have an `id` assigned, otherwise just use plain HTML `<input type="submit">` without a name.