# Changing Browser URL from backing bean in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

This is related to [Changing Browser URL from backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068466/changing-browser-url-from-backing-bean)

@balusc

How do I do the same thing in JSF 2? I have a search page with 6 different components (mostly PrimeFaces 3.0) for setting the search parameters. How can I get all the parameters to appear in the URL so that the user can share the results page using the URL?

I looked at PrettyFaces, and that seems to be capable of doing this in a better way, but I would rather make it work with just JSF2 if that is a simpler solution...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should either manually specify all the parameters via nested f:param tags like this:

```
<h:link outcome="nextPage">
    <f:param name="param1" value="val1" />
    <f:param name="param2" value="val2" />
</h:link>
```

or just specify includeViewParams parameter:

```
<h:link outcome="nextPage" includeViewParams="true">
```

The same goes for `h:button`

Comment: Thanks! I am using p:commandButton which doesn't support this attribute includeViewParams. It also using a backing bean to update a primefaces datatable. The code is
    p:commandButton update="data:table1" 
Please suggest!

Comment: Will includeViewParams work only when a new page is opened? In my case the same page is updated with new data... actually a p:dataTable is updated with new values when you click a p:commandButton.

Comment: @agileai 'p:commandButton' sends POST request to server. In order to include parameters in URL you have to make GET request which is achieved using h:button and 'h:link' (don't remember if it supports simple buttons for making GET requests). However, in your case you generate _Ajax request_ which is completely different. And I'm afraid in your case you won't be able to update browser URL, because Ajax does just partial processing of your view. Although I don't know why you may need it.

Comment: @jfrentic I thought as much regarding Ajax... I have a simple app that consists of a few pages. This particular page presents differents results that the user may want to share with others... Is there any other way I could create a shareable link? Maybe by creating a share button that creates a custom URL that gets processed by a special page that redirects to the results page with the required data displayed? I am just thinking aloud. Other than that I guess i will have to rethink the page design, which I would like to avoid if possible. Thanks again for your help with this!

Comment: @agileai From my level of expertise, I'd tell you, that it would be much easier to display the results on a separate page (that is, if you want to have bookmarkable URLs). However, I think it might be possible, by using hash in URL (such as http://hostname/myapp/mypage#param1=val. Just google for "Bookmarkable Ajax links" or something. If I find the answer, I will surely post it here. Glad if I was of any help.

Comment: Trying to make it work with two different pages. One query page and one results page. 

There seem to be two ways of sending a re-direct 1) in the xhtml using the outcome attribute, and 2) in the backing bean. When should one choose one over the other? Is there a good tutorial on this subject?

Comment: @agileai >> There seem to be two ways of sending a re-direct  No, also you could use 'h:commandButton' and 'h:commandLink' and in their **action** attribute specify outcome with '?faces-redirect=true' postfix. Also you could set up redirect rule in faces-confix.xml. Using outcome attribute seems to be more straightforward, however what to use is up to you. I would recommend reading **Core Java Faces** book (3rd Edition for JSF 2) which is truly a JSF bible.